# MakeHuman rig not moving with mesh after parenting

Tags: rigging, makehuman

Import figure direct into Blender from MakeHuman. Select all parts and join. Select figure/mesh and parent rig with weights. Move rig, figure/mesh moves with rig. Move figure/mesh and the rig is not attached.
[Man002](https://workupload.com/file/m9K2xaGLU4p)

Comment: The armature is the parent of the mesh, so it is not supposed to move when you move the mesh, it's the opposite, the mesh is supposed to move with the armature

Comment: So can I join the rig to the mesh so it moves with it?

Comment: The mesh is already parented to the armature so you're not supposed to do anything more, I'm not sure what you mean by "join the rig to the mesh"

Comment: So I cannot move the mesh and the rig follows? But can move the rig and the mesh follows?

Comment: yes that's it, the parent moves the child, not the opposite, same for armature that is parent of a mesh